# How to process the table below using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to process the table below using pandas?

The Input Excel:
[image]

I want to deduplicate the Hospital Name column, but put the data in this row into the corresponding hospital.

The Output Excel:
[image]

If pandas is used for processing, how should it be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple groupby and sum.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Mayo",3,nan],["Hopkins",1,nan],["MassGen",1,nan],["Mayo",nan,9],["Hopkins",nan,7],],columns=['Hospital','2023','2024'])
print(df)
grpd = df.groupby("Hospital").sum(min_count=1)
print(grpd)
```

```
  Hospital  2023  2024
0     Mayo   3.0   NaN
1  Hopkins   1.0   NaN
2  MassGen   1.0   NaN
3     Mayo   NaN   9.0
4  Hopkins   NaN   7.0

          2023  2024
Hospital            
Hopkins    1.0   7.0
MassGen    1.0   NaN
Mayo       3.0   9.0
```

Comment: ，If I want to add a column in front of the hospital column, the column name is the serial number, increasing from 1, how should I write the code?

Comment: That's easy too
`grpd.reset_index(inplace=True)`
`grpd.index=range(1,grpd.shape[0]+1)`
`print(grpd)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input file is in .xlsx format, make sure openpyxl is installed.

This solution gives you exactly the same output as seen in the output Excel keeping indices and the same order.

```
import pandas as pd

input_df = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx", index_col=0)

print(input_df)

input_df['Index'] = input_df.index

output_df = input_df.groupby('Hospital Name', as_index=False).first().set_index(["Index"]).sort_index()
output_df.index.name = None

print(output_df)
```

```
                              Hospital Name  202304 target  202304 complete  202303 target  202303 complete  202302 target  202302 complete
0                               Mayo Clinic           20.0             14.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
1            Massachusetts General Hospital           21.0             13.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
2                    Johns Hopkins Hospital           22.0             15.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
3                          Cleveland Clinic           23.0             16.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
4                       UCLA Medical Center           24.0             12.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
5            Northwestern Memorial Hospital           20.0             13.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
6   University of Washington Medical Center           21.0             15.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
7                  Duke University Hospital           22.0             17.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
8                      Mount Sinai Hospital           23.0             16.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
9                               Mayo Clinic            NaN              NaN           21.0             15.0            NaN              NaN
10           Massachusetts General Hospital            NaN              NaN           22.0             17.0            NaN              NaN
11                   Johns Hopkins Hospital            NaN              NaN           23.0             14.0            NaN              NaN
12                              Mayo Clinic            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN           24.0             16.0
13           Massachusetts General Hospital            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN           22.0             15.0
14                   Johns Hopkins Hospital            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN           23.0             13.0
15                      UCLA Medical Center            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN           25.0             15.0
                             Hospital Name  202304 target  202304 complete  202303 target  202303 complete  202302 target  202302 complete
0                              Mayo Clinic           20.0             14.0           21.0             15.0           24.0             16.0
1           Massachusetts General Hospital           21.0             13.0           22.0             17.0           22.0             15.0
2                   Johns Hopkins Hospital           22.0             15.0           23.0             14.0           23.0             13.0
3                         Cleveland Clinic           23.0             16.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
4                      UCLA Medical Center           24.0             12.0            NaN              NaN           25.0             15.0
5           Northwestern Memorial Hospital           20.0             13.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
6  University of Washington Medical Center           21.0             15.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
7                 Duke University Hospital           22.0             17.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
8                     Mount Sinai Hospital           23.0             16.0            NaN              NaN            NaN              NaN
```

Comment: If I want to increment the serial number of the first column from 1, how should I do it？

Comment: If you want to start the index with 1 instead of 0 or generally increment by 1 you can add this line at the end of your code:

output_df.index += 1